# These callbacks are driving me nuts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$("#to").autocomplete({

    //define callback to format results
    source: function(req, add) {

        //pass request to server
        $.getJSON("friends.php?callback=?", req, function(data) {

            //create array for response objects
            var suggestions = [];

            //process response
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                suggestions.push(val.name);
            });

            //pass array to callback
            add(suggestions);
        });
    }
});
```

[Source](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/)

I am trying to get familiar with the autocomplete functionality (jquery-ui) and then I come across

```
function (req, add).
```

How does it know that  `req` is the data that was entered?

Where is the callback `add` defined?

Can someone point me to a useful tutorial so  I can understand how to use these callbacks?

Answer (score 3):

It comes from the autocomplete plugin. See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete

> The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:
>
> - A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the user entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".
> - A response callback, which expects a single argument to contain the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with label/value/both properties). It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

**Update:**

The function you provide as callback (`source: function(req, add) {...}`) is called by the plugin and the plugin passes the arguments for these parameters. You can freely choose the name of the parameters though.

You can find the [source code on Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1-8-stable/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js). The function which is passed to your callback is defined in [line 134](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1-8-stable/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L134):

```
this.response = function() {
    return self._response.apply( self, arguments );
};
```

and the callback is called in [line 311](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1-8-stable/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L311) (`this.source` is your callback):

```
_search: function( value ) {
    this.pending++;
    this.element.addClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );

    this.source( { term: value }, this.response );
},
```

Comment: I may have read this a thousand time.  I can't seem to grasp the response callback. The "add"  method in particular. Where is that function defined?

Comment: It's defined and passed by the plugin. I will update the answer. *updated*.

Comment: Kling. Thanks For all your help, but how do you Javascript programmers trace all these anonymous method? Are there any tricks? It seems like suicide trying to delve into these anomymous methods. Any good tutorial outhere? Thanks Again.

Comment: Well, in order to *use* the plugin, you don't have to know where method is defined, etc. just follow the documentation. If you how to analyse the source code and find the definitions, I'd say that comes with experience.